# how to create 1 and half fr width of grid item

Tags: css, css-grid

i'm trying to make this component:

[component image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwoga.png)

This is my css code for this grid items:

```
#flight-tab {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

and this is my html structure:

```
  <div id="flight-tab">
    <div class="tab-box bg-white d-flex align-items-center text-left">
      <div>
        <svg class="sprite-icon">
          <use :xlink:href="`${sprite}#location`"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="title font-weight-bold">From</div>
        <div class="subtitle">Tehran (THR)</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-box bg-white d-flex align-items-center text-left">
      <div>
        <svg class="sprite-icon">
          <use :xlink:href="`${sprite}#flag`"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="title font-weight-bold">To</div>
        <div class="subtitle">Isfahan (IFN)</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-box bg-white d-flex align-items-center text-left">
      <div>
        <svg class="sprite-icon">
          <use :xlink:href="`${sprite}#calendar`"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="title font-weight-bold">Departure Date</div>
        <div class="subtitle">18 March 2019</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-box bg-white d-flex align-items-center text-left">
      <div>
        <svg class="sprite-icon">
          <use :xlink:href="`${sprite}#calendar`"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="title font-weight-bold">One Way</div>
        <div class="subtitle">No Return</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-box bg-white d-flex align-items-center text-left">
      <div>
        <svg class="sprite-icon">
          <use :xlink:href="`${sprite}#user`"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="title font-weight-bold">Passengers</div>
        <div class="subtitle">2 Adult | 1 Child | 0 Infant</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="search-btn">Search Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### How can I change the width of last item like that picture above?

Comment: make it 4 or 6 columns , there is no 0.5fr ;)

Comment: As suggested above, create a 6-column grid. 50% items will span columns 1-3 / 3-6. Make the longer item span columns 1-4.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, it would be best for you to divide the grid in more columns so it allows you to have a more flexible layout, here I made a 6-column grid and just told the last 2 items to distribute according to the space you need as per your image.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  gap: 15px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3,
.item4 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.item5 {
  grid-column: span 4
}

.item6 {
  grid-column: span 2
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item item1">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item item2">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item item3">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item item4">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item item5">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item item6">
  </div>
</div>
```